# Prove that $X$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let: $$S=\{(p,q,0)\in \mathbb{R}^3: p^2 +q^2<1, p\in \mathbb{Q}, q\in \mathbb{Q} \}$$ $$I(a,b) \text{ - open line segment between points } a, b$$
> Now let's define set $X$: $$X=\{(x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 +y^2 \leq 1\} \cup \Biggl( \bigcup_{(p,q,0)\in S} I\big((p,q,0),(p,q,p)\big) \Biggr) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$$ Prove that $X$ is connected.

I know from intuition that $X$ is linearly connected so also connected. However I don't know how I can prove it in formal way.

Comment: If the answer has not resolved your question, please elaborate. Otherwise, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, any path connected space is also connected, so it suffices to prove $X$ is path connected.

Now, the subset $
\{(x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 +y^2 \leq 1\}$ is definitely path connected. Furthermore, any point with nonzero height ($z$-coordinate) can be connected to a point in $
\{(x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 +y^2 \leq 1\}$ by a linear parametrization of the corresponding vertical interval. Finally, to connect *two* points of nonzero height, first connect each of them to (possibly distinct) points in $
\{(x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 +y^2 \leq 1\}$ which can then be connected using another *linear* path.

This gives a way to connect any two points in $X$ with a piecewise linear path, and such paths are continuous.

Comment: @RobertShore The base of $X$ is the whole disk, not just $S$.